# Is it possible to redo a while loop without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I can use some help with the following. I would like to change the content of my buttons after pressing the button. Is it possible to change a PHP variable from Javascript, or can I not do this because PHP is server-side?

After that I want to run a MySQL query with this new variable and use it in my **while** loop. I hope someone can help me.

**PHP:**

```
<?php 

$result = $conn->query($query_answer);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
?>

<input type="button" id="<?php echo $row["answer_id"];?>" next_question_id="<?php echo $row["next_question_id"];?>" value="<?php echo $row["answer_text"];?>" onclick=myFunction((this.id));>

<?php   
    }
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
function myFunction(clicked_id) {
    var button = clicked_id
    var next_question_id = document.getElementById(button).getAttribute("next_question_id"); 
        $.post ('next_question.php',{postnextquestionid:next_question_id},
            function (data) 
            {
                $('#question_text').html(data);
            });

}

</script>
```

Comment: why not just use ajax here, you already are so why not for this issue?

Comment: How I can user Ajax for this issue?

Comment: ajax calls php script that returns data you want and then populates the html page with it

Comment: Thknx, I write a query in my next_question.php file. 
How can i use this in Ajax?
And how can I reload the PHP While loop from Ajax?

Comment: your ajax above populates the page based from a php script based on a button push.

Comment: True, I do not know how to run the while loop again. So the buttons with new values ​​are shown.

Comment: "I do not know how to run the while loop again" you would call the code again, you may want to redactor this so the code is accessible in 2 locations, rather than duplicating it.